# What are the IPA equivalents for the special characters used to transscribe indian words?

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, transcription, transliteration, indian-languages

When I try to read an article related to India (in particular indo-aryan languages) certain special characters emerge which I do not know how to pronounciate. For instance:  Aṣṭādhyāyī of Pāṇini contains **ṣ,ṭ,ṇ** - but there are more.  I have tried to look them up in the IPA-list, but no such characters exist there.

- Is this a standardized transscription-system?
- Is it possible to allocate those special characters to IPA-characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [Wikipedia article on Sanskrit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit#Phonology) you can find all those special characters together with their IPA counterparts.
By the way, these special characters are parts of the [IAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration), the International Alphabet of Sanskrit Transliteration.